# Within 2 different sorted string lists, keep only the elements that match the substring number in both

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I successfully extracted the full path name of each file in two different directories into separate string lists. Each of the two lists now have strings corresponding to the full path + file name within the corresponding folders.

Each element in the firstList looks something like:

> "C:\users\me\path\anotherDirectory\firstFolder\actual_fileName_######.extension"

Similarly, in the secondList it looks something like:

> "C:\users\me\path\anotherDirectory\secondFolder\actual_fileName_######.extension"

the "######" part corresponds to 6 digits that I call the serial number.

Ideally, each file in the firstFolder will match the serial number with one in the secondFolder, but that's not always the case.

I want to remove those elements that do not have a matching serial number in both lists so that afterwards I should end up with the same two lists, but now every single string element in firstList has a matching serial number with one on secondList (and vice versa). No serial number should be repeated within the same list and they should remain sorted.

I had thought of some partial solutions, but they felt kind of convoluted and inefficient. I feel like this is something that can be done very concisely using LINQ, but I do not have the knowledge yet to do so.

Comment: you could use [tag:regex] to extract the `######` and [tag:linq] for checking whether a list of number exists in another list of number.

Comment: Do the “actual_fileName_” parts have to match as well?

Comment: "No string should be repeated within the same list" - this shouldn't be possible if they are filenames from single folders.

Comment: @Corvus, in my case they will probably all match, but they don't have to. I'm only care about the serial numbers.

Comment: @NetMage, true that. Edited to "No serial number should be repeated within the same list".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it! I basically just took [NetMage's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2557128/netmage) idea and adapted it a bit, so huge thanks to them, else I wouldn't have been able to solve it.

What worked for me was:

```
var serialNumRE = new Regex(@"_(\d+)\.", RegexOptions.Compiled);

var firstFolderSerialNums = firstFolderFiles.Select(path => serialNumRE.Match(Path.GetFileName(path)).Groups[1].Value);
var secondFolderSerialNums = secondFolderFiles.Select(path => serialNumRE.Match(Path.GetFileName(path)).Groups[1].Value);

var finalFirstFolderFiles = firstFolderFiles
                            .IntersectBy(secondFolderSerialNums, path => serialNumRE.Match(Path.GetFileName(path)).Groups[1].Value)
                            .ToList();

var finalSecondFolderFiles = secondFolderFiles
                            .IntersectBy(firstFolderSerialNums, path => serialNumRE.Match(Path.GetFileName(path)).Groups[1].Value)
                            .ToList();
```

If anybody has a more efficient solution or a way of doing it using better practices, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Regex` to extract the serial numbers, you can use `Enumerable.ExceptBy` (.Net Core) to create two new lists:

```
var serialNumRE = new Regex(@"_(\d+).", RegexOptions.Compiled);

var finalFirstFolderFiles = firstFolderFiles
                                .ExceptBy(secondFolderFiles, fp => serialNumRE.Match(Path.GetFileName(fp)).Groups[1].Value)
                                .ToList();

var finalSecondFolderFiles = secondFolderFiles
                                .ExceptBy(firstFolderFiles, fp => serialNumRE.Match(Path.GetFileName(fp)).Groups[1].Value)
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome! It didn't directly work but it helped me understand a few concepts and managed to adapt it a bit to solve it. I simply needed to extract the serial numbers first, so the query arguments worked. I also edited the regex to know the serial number should be right before the '.' for the file extension, since it might not work if there are digits within the parent directories' names.

Comment: @JanBadillo It would have to be extra digits in the filename (`Path.GetFileName` extracts just the filename with extension) and they would have to be proceeded by `_` and followed by `.` in front of the first extension (when the file has multiple extensions) so I don't see how you could identify the serial # in that case :) The regex pattern `@"_(\d+)."` says extract the digits preceded by `_` and followed by `.`

Comment: Oh you're right. Totally missed that. I just used a website to see if the regex extracted the serial number, but I only tested it using the full path and forgot about GetFileName().